# How do I format a json struct with multiple object returns? (Dynamic)

Tags: json, struct, go

I have an API call and it returns like this:

```
{
    "result": {
        "720268538": {
            "icon_url": "-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXU5A1PIYQNqhpOSV-fRPasw8rsUFJ5KBFZv668FFEuh_KQJTtEuI63xIXbxqOtauyClTMEsJV1jruS89T3iQKx_BBqa2j3JpjVLFH1xpp0EQ",
            "icon_url_large": "",
            "icon_drag_url": "",
            "name": "Chroma Case",
            "market_hash_name": "Chroma Case",
            "market_name": "Chroma Case",
            "name_color": "D2D2D2",
            "background_color": "",
            "type": "Base Grade Container",
            "tradable": "1",
            "marketable": "1",
            "commodity": "1",
            "market_tradable_restriction": "7",
            "fraudwarnings": "",
            "descriptions": {
                "0": {
                    "type": "html",
                    "value": " ",
                    "app_data": ""
                },
                "1": {
                    "type": "html",
                    "value": "Container Series #38",
                    "color": "99ccff",
                    "app_data": ""
                },
                "2": {
                    "type": "html",
                    "value": " ",
                    "app_data": ""
                },
                "3": {
                    "type": "html",
                    "value": "Contains one of the following:",
                    "app_data": ""
                },
                "4": {
                    "type": "html",
                    "value": "Glock-18 | Catacombs",
                    "color": "4b69ff",
                    "app_data": ""
                },
                "5": {
                    "type": "html",
                    "value": "M249 | System Lock",
                    "color": "4b69ff",
                    "app_data": ""
                },
                "6": {
                    "type": "html",
                    "value": "MP9 | Deadly Poison",
                    "color": "4b69ff",
                    "app_data": ""
                },
                "7": {
                    "type": "html",
                    "value": "SCAR-20 | Grotto",
                    "color": "4b69ff",
                    "app_data": ""
                },
                "8": {
                    "type": "html",
                    "value": "XM1014 | Quicksilver",
                    "color": "4b69ff",
                    "app_data": ""
                },
                "9": {
                    "type": "html",
                    "value": "Dual Berettas | Urban Shock",
                    "color": "8847ff",
                    "app_data": ""
                },
                "10": {
                    "type": "html",
                    "value": "Desert Eagle | Naga",
                    "color": "8847ff",
                    "app_data": ""
                },
                "11": {
                    "type": "html",
                    "value": "MAC-10 | Malachite",
                    "color": "8847ff",
                    "app_data": ""
                },
                "12": {
                    "type": "html",
                    "value": "Sawed-Off | Serenity",
                    "color": "8847ff",
                    "app_data": ""
                },
                "13": {
                    "type": "html",
                    "value": "AK-47 | Cartel",
                    "color": "d32ce6",
                    "app_data": ""
                },
                "14": {
                    "type": "html",
                    "value": "M4A4 | 龍王 (Dragon King)",
                    "color": "d32ce6",
                    "app_data": ""
                },
                "15": {
                    "type": "html",
                    "value": "P250 | Muertos",
                    "color": "d32ce6",
                    "app_data": ""
                },
                "16": {
                    "type": "html",
                    "value": "AWP | Man-o'-war",
                    "color": "eb4b4b",
                    "app_data": ""
                },
                "17": {
                    "type": "html",
                    "value": "Galil AR | Chatterbox",
                    "color": "eb4b4b",
                    "app_data": ""
                },
                "18": {
                    "type": "html",
                    "value": "or an Exceedingly Rare Special Item!",
                    "color": "ffd700",
                    "app_data": ""
                },
                "19": {
                    "type": "html",
                    "value": " ",
                    "app_data": ""
                },
                "20": {
                    "type": "html",
                    "value": "",
                    "color": "00a000",
                    "app_data": {
                        "limited": "1"
                    }
                }
            },
            "owner_descriptions": "",
            "tags": {
                "0": {
                    "internal_name": "CSGO_Type_WeaponCase",
                    "name": "Container",
                    "category": "Type",
                    "category_name": "Type"
                },
                "1": {
                    "internal_name": "set_community_6",
                    "name": "The Chroma Collection",
                    "category": "ItemSet",
                    "category_name": "Collection"
                },
                "2": {
                    "internal_name": "normal",
                    "name": "Normal",
                    "category": "Quality",
                    "category_name": "Category"
                },
                "3": {
                    "internal_name": "Rarity_Common",
                    "name": "Base Grade",
                    "category": "Rarity",
                    "color": "b0c3d9",
                    "category_name": "Quality"
                }
            },
            "classid": "720268538"
        },
        "success": true
    }
}
```

Result can have multiple returns I was wondering how the struct should look, this is what I have so far but it returns like nothing.

```
type AssetInfo struct {
    Result `json:"result"`
}

type Result struct {
    Asset   map[string]Asset `json:"asset"`
    Success bool             `json:"success,omitempty"`
}

type Asset struct {
    IconUrl           string                   `json:"icon_url,omitempty"`
    IconUrlLarge      string                   `json:"icon_url_large,omitempty"`
    IconDragUrl       string                   `json:"icon_drag_url,omitempty"`
    Name              string                   `json:"name,omitempty"`
    MarketHashName    string                   `json:"market_hash_name,omitempty"`
    MarketName        string                   `json:"market_name,omitempty"`
    NameColor         string                   `json:"name_color,omitempty"`
    BGColor           string                   `json:"background_color,omitempty"`
    Type              string                   `json:"type,omitempty"`
    Tradable          string                   `json:"tradable,omitempty"`
    Marketable        string                   `json:"marketable,omitempty"`
    Commodity         string                   `json:"commodity,omitempty"`
    TradeRestrict     string                   `json:"market_tradeable_restriction,omitempty"`
    FraudWarnings     string                   `json:"fraudwarnings,omitempty"`
    Descriptions      map[string]*Descriptions `json:"descriptions,omitempty"`
    OwnerDescriptions string                   `json:"owner_descriptions,omitempty"`
    Tags              map[string]*Tags         `json:"tags,omitempty"`
    ClassId           string                   `json:"classid,omitempty"`
}

type Descriptions struct {
    Type    string `json:"type"`
    Value   string `json:"value"`
    Color   string `json:"color,omitempty"`
    AppData string `json:"appdata"`
}

type Tags struct {
    InternalName string `json:"internal_name"`
    Name         string `json:"name"`
    Category     string `json:"category"`
    Color        string `json:"color,omitempty"`
    CategoryName string `json:"category_name"`
}
```

If anybody could tell me what's wrong with my struct that would be great thanks.

The thing that confuses me is like how Descriptions returns not an array but multiple objects that could range from 0-20 how do I prepare a struct for this when I don't know how many objects are going to return, as well `result` can return multiple `"720616831"` so how should this look?

Comment: The struct in my answer is quite similar to where you are right now, see the latest edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to kick yourself for the first mistake -- your JSON has `result` but your struct tag has `response`.

The second problem is a trickier one. The thing is that you declared that your `Asset` map is nested inside the result as a key called "asset", but that's not true. Actually it's just all of the keys of the result *other* than success/error. Unfortunately, `encoding/json` doesn't have any way to express this. You can say that `result` is a `map[string]interface{}`, and then success/error if they exist will be bool/string, and the assets will be more `map[string]interface{}`s containing keys for all of the other fields. That works, but it's a bit ugly/inefficient, and a lot of work if you want to convert into a proper struct type so that you can have methods on it.

Maybe a better way to go is to decode into this type:

```
type AssetIntermediate struct {
    Result map[string]json.RawMessage `json:"result"`
}
```

as well as having

```
type Asset struct { /* all those fields */ }
type AssetInfo struct {
    Success bool
    Error string
    Assets map[string]Asset
}
```

Then you can do

```
var intermediate AssetIntermediate
err := json.Unmarshal(data, &intermediate)
/* handle err */

var ai AssetInfo

/* At this point, intermediate.Result is a map
 * of strings to json.RawMessage, which is just a []byte
 * containing not-yet-decoded JSON. We want to take
 * each field and put it into ai where it belongs.
 */
for k, v := range intermediate.Result {
    var err error
    // error and success keys are decoded into the respective fields
    if k == "error" {
        err = json.Unmarshal(v, &ai.Error)
    } else if k == "success" {
        err = json.Unmarshal(v, &ai.Success)
    } else {
        // Otherwise, we have an asset. First decode it...
        var asset Asset
        err = json.Unmarshal(v, &asset)
        if err == nil {
            // Create the Assets map if it doesn't exist yet
            if ai.Assets == nil {
                ai.Assets = map[string]Asset{}
            }
            // And store the asset in the map under the key k.
            ai.Assets[k] = asset
        }
    }
    /* handle err if non-nil */
}
```

which is a lot more work than a single `Decode` call, but it should basically do the right thing.

If all of this is inside a function that returns `(*AssetInfo, error)` then the right thing to put in place of `/* Handle err */` might be

```
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, in `range intermediate` what is `intermediate` in this, is this some variable somewhere or?

Comment: @Datsik it's the `AssetIntermediate` that you decoded the original JSON into.

Comment: Damn you're good! Would it be too much to ask for you to comment out your answer just to explain what exactly is happening that would be fantastic. Thanks. I've only been using Go for maybe 2-3 weeks I'm not sure why you need a `Reader` in this

Comment: @Datsik I added some comments and fixed a small error. Better?

Comment: @Datsik actually you don't, force of habit. I'll change it to use `Unmarshal` :)

Comment: Hey thanks a lot that's awesome, I'm also used to using `json.NewDecoder().Decode()` but to each their own haha - https://github.com/Gacnt/go-steam-market is what I was working on and it's now up to my liking :)

Comment: `NewDecoder` only takes an `io.Reader`, `Unmarshal` takes a `[]byte`. We already have a `[]byte` so it is kind of silly to wrap it in a `bytes.Reader` just to be able to use `NewDecoder` :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest playing with the base `map[string]interface{}` type and iterating  from the json string until you can build the whole struct. For the parts where you don't really know the keys, such as the 0-20, the map may be all you'll have.

For example, suppose the string your example is in variable `j`. You could start with:

```
type AssetInfo struct {
    Result map[string]interface{}
}
```

and start unmarshaling and printing in order to find the full struct:

```
var ai AssetInfo
json.Unmarshal([]byte(j), &ai)
fmt.Printf("%#v\n", ai)
```

This prints the entire map built after unmarshaling. Trying to build the whole struct beforehand with such a complex structure is unlikely to get you results.

EDIT: If you treat Result as a `map[string]struct` like you did with `Descriptions` the Success bool is "lost" and goes into the map but the rest of the json unmarshals correctly. I don't see a way to support the `Success` bool as well as a map for the rest of the structure. As for the numbered keys, if you need a slice, you'll have to do some work after the unmarshal.

```
type AssetInfo struct {
    Result map[string]Numbered
}

type Numbered struct {
    IconUrl          string                 `json:"icon_url"`
    IconUrlLarge     string                 `json:"icon_url_large"`
    IconDragUrl      string                 `json:"icon_drag_url"`
    Name             string                 `json:"name"`
    MarketHashName   string                 `json:"market_hash_name"`
    MarketName       string                 `json:"market_name"`
    NameColor        string                 `json:"name_color"`
    BGColor          string                 `json:"background_color"`
    Type             string                 `json:"type"`
    Tradable         string                 `json:"tradable"`
    Marketable       string                 `json:"marketable"`
    Commodity        string                 `json:"commodity"`
    TradeRestrict    string                 `json:"market_tradeable_restriction"`
    FraudWarnings    string                 `json:"fraudwarnings"`
    Descriptions     map[string]description `json:"descriptions"`
    OwnerDescription string                 `json:"owner_descriptions"`
    Tags             map[string]tag         `json:"tags"`
    ClassID          string                 `json:"classid"`
}

type description struct {
    Type    string `json:"type"`
    Value   string `json:"value"`
    Color   string `json:"color,omitempty"`
    AppData string `json:"appdata"`
}

type tag struct {
    InternalName string `json:"internal_name"`
    Name         string `json:"name"`
    Category     string `json:"category"`
    Color        string `json:"color,omitempty"`
    CategoryName string `json:"category_name"`
}

func main() {
    var ai AssetInfo
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(j), &ai)
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", ai.Result["720268538"].Tags)
}
```

The output of the `Tags` is `map[0:{InternalName:CSGO_Type_WeaponCase Name:Container Category:Type Color: CategoryName:Type} 1:{InternalName:set_community_6 Name:The Chroma Collection Category:ItemSet Color: CategoryName:Collection} (...)`

EDIT 2: After discussion in the comments I ended up at some code which is very similar to hobbs' answer. His might be better organized.

We need to use `json.RawMessage` since the `true` value for `"success"` can't go into the `Numbered` struct.

```
type AssetInfo struct {
    Result map[string]json.RawMessage
}

err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(j), &ai)
fmt.Println("outer error", err) // prints <nil>
for k, v := range ai.Result {
    // this is very similar to the example on the docs: https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#RawMessage
    var dst interface{} 
    if k == "success" {
        dst = new(bool)
    } else {
        dst = new(Numbered)
    }
    err := json.Unmarshal(v, dst)
    fmt.Println("inner error", err) // prints <nil>
    if k == "success" {
        b := dst.(*bool)
        fmt.Printf("%t\n", *b) // true
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("%+v\n", dst) // the whole Numbered struct
    }
}
```

Comment: We have the exact same stuff but I'm getting: `json: cannot unmarshal bool into Go value of type gosm.Numbered`

Comment: I wasn't checking my error return on the `Unmarshal`, a similar message shows for me. It's the `success`, it can't go into the struct.

Comment: It happens because `"success"` only has the `true` value, not the full struct which I'm calling `Numbered`. We need to use `json.RawMessage` to separate it, I'll post another edit.

Comment: Thanks I'm going to try this out and see if it works... Why does this seem so much more convoluted than it needs to be?

Comment: Check hobbs' answer too, he is more concise and I think arrives at a better solution. In my opinion, the json string is very weird, it doesn't map well to any struct I can think of. In these cases we need to do extra work.